# How can I set an Atom Grammar based on file content?

Tags: grammar, atom-editor

In Sublime Text 3 there is a package called [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) which allows to set syntax highlighting based on file contents. How could this be achieved in Atom?

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the [specs](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/f48069c5f848b5ae624b110a1df7800e919eb142/spec/grammars-spec.coffee) I noticed that Atom does actually support content based grammar selection:

```
it "uses the filePath's shebang line if the grammar cannot be determined by the extension or basename", -> 
  filePath = require.resolve("./fixtures/shebang") 
  expect(atom.grammars.selectGrammar(filePath).name).toBe "Ruby"
```

The way Atom works is by calculating a grammar score based upon the *file path* and the *content of the file*.

More specifically and in relation to content each grammar contains a `firstLineMatch` which is a regex that looks at the first line or few lines that helps to determine if the file does indeed belong to that grammar, in the case of [Ruby](https://github.com/atom/language-ruby/blob/master/grammars/ruby.cson) this is:

```
'firstLineMatch': '^#!\\s*/.*\\bruby|^#\\s+-\\*-\\s*ruby\\s*-\\*-'
```

This looks for the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) or an equivalent comment found in some Ruby files.

Related Reading:

- [Open .rb files with RoR grammar by default instead of Ruby](https://discuss.atom.io/t/open-rb-files-with-ror-grammar-by-default-instead-of-ruby/14093/5)
- [Atom Flight Manual: Grammar](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/grammar/)

Comment: In that case, and without reading links, could a matching regex be specified for content other than first line?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any inherent support for doing so, however you may be able to create a regex that matched numerous new line characters to look for a firstLine + 1 or more new lines + the string you are looking for - that's probably a whole other question though.

Comment: That's precisely what can be achieved in St3, one or more regex to match. If one or more match (depending on configuration) then the grammar applies. Amazing huh.